# duplicate data in opposite column

Tags: sql, oracle, netezza

I have a table which has two fields lets say col1 and col2

```
DATA AS
col1,col2
10,age
20,30
30,param
age,10
30,20
param,30
```

Each row is duplicate but in reverse column order

```
say 
10,age
age,20
```

In my final output i just want single row to be present among the duplicate one, so final
output will be like

```
col1,col2
10,age
20,30
30,param
```

only three rows will be left rest rows will be ignored according to the given scenario

I have tried across so many different ways but can't find the solution.
So if any of you can help or just provide an approach then it will be a great help

Thanks

Comment: sorry, dont really understand what you want, would you mind to further explain?

Comment: but what do you want to do with your duplicates? find the duplicats? filter out the duplicats? are columns always duplicated or sometimes?

Comment: Thanks for taking interests    after processing the query only 3 rows will be selected in the select query it means filter out rest rows

Comment: If `col1` will never be equal to `col2` you might simply use `where col1 < col2`

Comment: Sorry i didn't explain you correctly the data set is not based on integer datatype its a varchar based data type.

Comment: `where col1 < col2` would still work on a varchar column

Answer (score 3):

```
select distinct col1,col2 from t t1
where col1<=col2
or not exists (select 1 from t where t.col1=t1.col2
                                      and 
                                      t.col2=t1.col1)
```

[SqlFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/c62c8/1)

Comment: This is good, will work also for col1=col2 values http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/b1804/1

Comment: good solution but if i have character say nvarchar datatype like 10 'age' and the corresponding row 'age' 10, then it might not work

Comment: @AnkitKansal In this case you should convert Col1 and Col2 to the common type (for instance VARCHAR()) when you compare them.

Answer (score 1):

You can do the same using **[Greatest and Least](http://www.adp-gmbh.ch/ora/sql/greatest_least.html)**

```
select distinct 
least("col1","col2") AS "col1"
,greatest("col1","col2") as "col2"
from Table1
order by "col1"
```

**[SQL Fiddle 1](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/39299/3)**

According to Updated Question **[SQL Fiddle 2](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/6ec11/1)**

Comment: @AnkitKansal check my answer. it will take the least time.

Comment: nice work but it might not work if the data type taken is in varchar say 10 'age' 'age' 10 . but great logic...

Comment: In that case you can use **[cast and convert function](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17952_01/refman-5.0-en/charset-convert.html) `cast(col2 as char(50))`**

Comment: good solution seems to be perfectly working in Oracle database. Do you have any idea how to implement this in Netezza as Netezza doesn't support Least,Greatest Function

Comment: I from Mumbai. But did my Eng from Pune

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't this be enough?

```
SELECT * 
FROM Data 
WHERE Col1 < Col2
```

(if you are sure every row has a duplicate pair)